# Area between lines and parabolas (in description)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find the area of the region enclosed by the parabola $y=x^2-3x$, the line $y=2x$, and the line $y=x$.

This time, I could not break up the area into more parts, so I did not know how to calculate the area. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

[image]

\begin{align*}
\text{Area}&=\int_0^4\left(2x-x\right)dx+\int_4^5\left[2x-\left(x^2-3x\right)\right]dx
\end{align*}